# Apps Script running slowing moving values from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script

I've posted a similar problem before and received a great suggestion but this one is slightly different. I am copying data from cells from one sheet to another but the destination is slightly different.  Is there a faster way to do this?  I know getting and setting values slows it down, however, I'm not sure how I would assign the values to an array and set in the right cells.

Code below, suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks Fazila

```
for (var i = 0; i < simsTimetableLastRow; i++) {
    try {
      
      if(searchRangeVals[i][0].indexOf("Timetable") > -1) {
                
        copyRows = simsTimetable.getRange(i + 1, 1, 2, 11);
        pasteRowsLoc = newTimetable.getRange(j + 1, 1, 2, 11).setValues(copyRows.getValues());
        copyRows.copyFormatToRange(newTimetable, 1, 11, j + 1, j + 3);
        pasteTemplateLoc = newTimetable.getRange(j + 4, 1, 25, 11);
        pasteTemplateLoc.setValues(templateVals);
        template.copyFormatToRange(newTimetable, 1, 11, j + 4, j + 25);

        period1To2 = simsTimetable.getRange(i + 6, 2, 4, 11).getValues();
        newTimetable.getRange(j + 6, 2, 4, 11).setValues(period1To2);
        
        period3 = simsTimetable.getRange(i + 11, 2, 2, 11).getValues();
        newTimetable.getRange(j + 10, 2, 2, 11).setValues(period3);
        
        period3To4 = simsTimetable.getRange(i + 11, 2, 4, 11).getValues();
        newTimetable.getRange(j + 14, 2, 4, 11).setValues(period3To4);
        
        period5 = simsTimetable.getRange(i + 15, 2, 2, 11).getValues();
        newTimetable.getRange(j + 18, 2, 2, 11).setValues(period5);
        newTimetable.getRange(j + 22, 2, 2, 11).setValues(period5);
        
        period6ToReg = simsTimetable.getRange(i + 19, 2, 4, 11).getValues();
        newTimetable.getRange(j + 24, 2, 4, 11).setValues(period6ToReg);
                 
        j = j + 33;
                
      }
    } catch(e) {
      Logger.log(i);
    }
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean with the destination being slightly different? Could you share your workflow and a copy of the sheet to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

Processing times are significantly longer when your script interacts with your spreadsheet, compared to it processing data within the allocated memory. So in order to speed this up, you'd ideally pull all data that you'll need from the spreadsheet into memory in one go, and then also write back everything you need to in another go.

So, rather than getting values row by row, get all values from the sheet in question, eg:

```
var data = simsTimetable.getRange(2, 1, simsTimetable.getLastRow()-1, simsTimetable.getLastColumn());
```

and work with that within the script.

Similarly, rather than writing into the new sheet every time, initiate a temp array

```
var tempArray = [];
```

and whenever you'd write in in, just push the data into this array row by row.

Mind you that you will have to do some maths to get the right data from the `data` array and also to build your `tempArray` in a way that you can write that into the new sheet in one step, but it's well worth it. It may be that for practical reasons you will need to reconsider your spreadsheet structure (so that columns you copy from/to) are next to each other, but you might already be lucky.